# CIL instruction "isinst <valuetype>"

Tags: cil

The ECMA Common Language Infrastructure documentation says this about the CIL "isinst *class*" instruction:

> Correct CIL ensures that *class* is a valid typeref or typedef or typespec token indicating a class, and
>   that *obj* is always either null or an object reference.

This implies that a valuetype is not allowed, right? But mscorlib.dll contains a method System.RuntimeTypeHandle::Equals(object obj) with the following instruction:

> IL_0001:  isinst     System.RuntimeTypeHandle

And System.RuntimeTypeHandle is a valuetype. Can anybody put me right here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the declaration of `RuntimeTypeHandle`:

```
.class public sequential ansi serializable sealed beforefieldinit RuntimeTypeHandle
    extends     System.ValueType
    implements  System.Runtime.Serialization.ISerializable
```

Although `RuntimeTypeHandle` is declared as a struct its representation in CIL is some kind of special class. In other words, you can imagine structs as special classes that inherit from `System.ValueType` and whose attributes follow a strict order.

With that in mind `isinst` would be callable with `RuntimeTypeHandle`. For what I interpret `isinst` is not limited to reference types at all as long as there is a class representing the type.

Let's say we write in C#:

```
var i = 4;
var b = i is Int32;
```

We get a compiler warning

> Warning: The given expression is always of the provided ('int') type.

What happens? We assign `4` to `i`. `i`becoms an `int`. On the next line `i`is being auto-boxed to its corresponding `ReferenceType` (class), so that the warning is obvious. We could even write

```
var b = i is int;
```

I hope this can contribute to some kind of clearification on this topic.

Comment: In other words, "isinst <valuetype>" really means "isinst <boxed valuetype>"?

Comment: @TonyK - I believe that is correct - note that your cited portion of the spec indicates that _obj_ must be null or an object reference, so it wouldn't make sense for it to be an unboxed value type.

Comment: Actually, `is int` is translated to `isinst int32`. In Reflector `int32` can be clicked and references to `System.Int32`. The same with other value types like `bool`.